# How to iterate through a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have below array when I send print_r command,

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => /Applications/AMPPS/www/supportcenter/uploads/attachments/2/cat.jpeg 
[1] => /Applications/AMPPS/www/supportcenter/uploads/attachments/2/images.jpeg 
[2] => /Applications/AMPPS/www/supportcenter/uploads/attachments/2/3672_00116.pdf         ))
```

I want to echo or get values of path to send as email in codeigniter, means $attachment = /path/image.png etc. so file will be attached.

```
$this->email->attach($attachment);
```

I tried as below but not working,

```
$attachments_array[] = $this->input->post('attachments');
    //print_r($attachments_array);

    foreach($attachments_array as $attachment)
    {
        //echo $attachment;
       $this->email->attach($attachment);
    }

    $this->email->send();
```

$this->input->post('attachments') is an array sent with ajax,

How can I do this?

Comment: **Tip: Loop twice(Nested)**

Comment: @Uchiha, its not working, i tried that,

Comment: Post your attempts what you have tried

Comment: @Uchiha, i did foreach(X as Y){ X1[ ] = Y; foreach(X1 as X){ echo X} }; but not worked

Answer (score 0):

Your post parameter "attachments" seems to be an array for itself

```
$this->input->post('attachments');
```

So you don't have to store it in another array (there's no need for another dimension).

The correct code would look something like this:

```
//note the missing []
$attachments_array = $this->input->post('attachments');

if(is_array($attachments_array)) { //null would also return false
    foreach($attachments_array as $attachment)
    {
        //echo $attachment;
       $this->email->attach($attachment);
    }
}

$this->email->send();
```

Comment: i tried that as well, but it shows Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() at line of foreach.

Comment: Is it possible that you're missing the the attachements array in your second attempt? When 'attachments' is null, you'll receive the stated error. I'll add such a check in the answer.

Comment: yes i found some issue with my AJAX value sending as string, i shorted it and now my code is working with 2 foreach loops, but something went wrong on this stackoverflow page, there was many comments and i posted too that it was solved, but not visible here, !

Comment: @rjcode do you really need the second dimension? In your provided snippet it would be useless; please update your snippet if you use the second dimension or mark this one as answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

May be try this

```
 foreach ($attachments_array as $attachment) {
    if (is_array($attachment)) {
        foreach ($attachment as $key => $value) {
            $this->email->attach($value);
        }
    } else {
        $this->email->attach($attachment);
    }
}
```